# Can I use a session token instead of a session?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, session

I've got a usecase called edit that seems to require a session since registration and keeping an OpenID / OAuth account isn't required. So I rolled my own authentication system med SHA1 that can check a password and now I want to know if I can implement the function to edit an article without bringing an own session object. Can it be done with a token that expires some way? The user needs to be "logged in" but all I have to implement is to enable edit an object and since users can be logged in just by sending an email I think login can be done with a session token. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called a "cookie-based session" by libraries such as [Beaker](http://beaker.groovie.org/sessions.html#cookie-based). Ideally, you should simply use Beaker or another library that provides such functionality, but in any case here's a lowdown on how they work:

The session data (which could just be a user identifier, or a flag indicating they have permission) is stored in a regular client-side cookie. It's optionally encrypted with a secret key, and it's stored alongside an [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hmac) generated using a *different* key. The optional encryption prevents the user from reading the data, and the HMAC ensures they can't modify it.

As a side-note, you say "registration and keeping an OpenID account isn't required", but then talk about your own authentication using SHA1 and passwords. Please bear in mind: Getting authentication right can be tricky, and few users want to sign up for another account with its own password when they could use an existing account to sign in.

Comment: Very interesting. I heard another story that I couldn't really believe which is that own authentication is preferable when I think many developers and users agree that OpenID is very convenient.